# How should I understand "en" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms, antécédent

> C'est toujours la même chose. La nourriture est toujours détestable, et les prisonniers sont toujours innocents. Ce qu'ils désirent, c'est toujours la liberté. ***En*** avez-vous d'autres?

I learned this sentence from *[Graded French Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618574743)*.

- In the last sentence, how should I understand "en"?
- What is its function in grammar?
- Doesn't "Avez-vous d'autres" mean "Do you have something else?"

Comment: Please give proper attribution to any book excerpt or quote.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: I have edited the question accordingly. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*En*" is referring to the prisoners. The governor has already been visiting several prisoners and he is asking to the director if there are more of them to visit:

> Do you have more prisoners (that you plan me to visit)?

Edit: [Here](http://www.dumaspere.com/pages/bibliotheque/chapitre.php?lid=r14&cid=14) is the original *Le Comte de Monte-Cristo* chapter.

Comment: I suppose you relied on more context than what was shown in the question. From the exerpt alone the antecedent is rather unclear.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez You are definitely right. The excerpt provided isn't enough to sort out the antecedent. This question, like many similar ones lately, is from Alexandre Dumas's *Le Comte de Monte-Cristo*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just added the reference in the question. It is indeed from Dumas's Le Comte de Monte-Cristo.

Answer (score 1):

*En* can be several things in French (preposition, adverb, adverbial pronoun, among others). In the [sentence referred to by @jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/22010/358):

> L'inspecteur se tourna en souriant, et dit au gouverneur :
>   « Je ne sais pas pourquoi on nous fait faire ces tournées inutiles. Qui voit un prisonnier en voit cent ; qui entend un prisonnier en entend mille ; c'est toujours la même chose : mal nourris et innocents. **En** avez-vous d'autres ?
>   - Oui, nous avons les prisonniers dangereux ou fous, que nous gardons au cachot.

we know it is an adverbial pronoun because of what comes before :

> Qui voit un prisonnier en voit cent ; qui entend un prisonnier en entend mille

and what comes after :

> Oui, nous avons les prisonniers dangereux ou fous, que nous gardons au cachot.

If the quote was stopped just after *qui entend un prisonnier en entend mille* we could understand *en* as meaning "such/similar prisoners".  But what comes after makes it clear that *en* does not stand for "similar prisoners" but for "different type(s) of prisoners", i.e. prisoners who do not only have to say they are innocent or not fed properly. I'd translate the sentence with :
"Do you have a different type of prisoners?"

**Doesn't "Avez-vous d'autres" mean "Do you have something else?"**

<strike>*Avez-vous d'autres*</strike> is not possible. Something is missing :

> Avez-vous quelque chose d'autre ?
>
> Avez-vous des prisonniers différents ?

And if context makes it clear we are talking about "different prisoners" we can use *en* :

> En avez-vous d'autres ?

---

This answer has been given after OP posted a [question on meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/627/358) and from context given in @Jiliagre's answer. The modified text in the graded reader referred to by OP might be different, the exact quote from the graded reader is missing from OP's question.

Comment: Is *adverbial pronouns* an English term frequently used to refer to the [French clitics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns) [*en*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns#The_pronoun_en) and [*y*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_personal_pronouns#The_pronoun_y) which stand for prepositional phrases? This is quite confusing as they seem to have nothing in common with adverbs.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't explain the grammar behind this and am answering purely by intuition (I am a native french speaker).
"En avez-vous d'autres" means "Do you have more of them". Leaving out "En" and saying "Avez-vous d'autres" wouldn't work. The best comparison I can come up with is saying "Have you more?" in english.